# Move .ssh folder from /var/root/

Tags: macos, ssh, root

I tried to set up a ssh key for easily logging into the server which is hosting my website : `ssh-keygen -t dsa -b 1024`.
The keys (public and private) have been saved in `/var/root/.ssh` which I dont like because I have to `sudo -s` prior to rsync for accessing the private key.

Is there any easy and safe way to move the ssh folder from `/var/root/.ssh` to my user folder, so that I can use the keys even if not root ? what location to move it ? what is the command for newbie to be used for the relocation ? (for mac os 10.10)
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've simply created a DSA key as root, it would be safest to do the following (from a terminal as your own user):

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
sudo cp -av /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa.pub /Users/$USER/.ssh/
chown -v $USER: ~/.ssh/id_dsa*
chmod -v 600 ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

This will create a `.ssh` configuration directory in your homedir (`mkdir -p` won't make loud noises if `~.ssh` already exists, and won't do anything), copy the public and private key files from `root`'s homedir to your own, then set the correct permissions and ownership on your files.

This is non-destructive (you're not moving anything, you're just copying); once you're happy the key-pair is letting you connect to your remote host successfully as your normal login user, you can `sudo rm -fv /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` This also doesn't affect any other files in either account's `.ssh` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Open Terminal while logged in as your usual user, then run

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
sudo sh -c 'mv /var/root/.ssh/* /Users/'$USER'/.ssh/'
sudo chown $USER ~/.ssh/*
sudo chgrp $(groups | cut -d \  -f 1) ~/.ssh/*
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
```

**This assumes that you haven't created any ssh key pairs as your usual used (and therefore don't already have files in `~/.ssh`).**

PS: Some explanations:

- First `sudo` moves the content of root's .ssh folder into the one of the current user. Needs to be done by calling a subshell (`sh -c`) because the wildcard part (`/var/root/.ssh/*`) only works after the `sudo` has changed the current user to root. `$USER` is an environment variable containing the name of the current user
- Third `sudo` changes group ownership of the copied files to the primary group of the current user. As there is no convenient environment variable for this, the output of `groups` (which lists all groups a user belongs to) needs to used. Please note the two space characters after the `\`.

Comment: I understand the plan, Patrix, yet I can't get line number 2 working : when logged as `xxx:~gilles$` it asks me my password, and fails : No such file or directory. Remark, if I write `sudo -s`, prompt is : `bash-3.2 #` and then I can list (ls) `/var/root/.ssh`

Comment: Ah, bugger. Edited, please try again.

Comment: It looks like it is successfull post. In my first attempt in copying your commands, I failed because I did not take care at the syntax (`cut -d \  -f 1`) where there are 2 needed blank spaces. I will test it tomorrow and try to understand the basics ;).

Comment: I have used this solution, yet following (untested) neuro's answer seems safer, at least for blind newbie.